# Select Elements that have Data Attribute Equal to Anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard, show, custom-data-attribute

I'm using jQuery to show and hide elements and need to pass a data attribute value that will 'show all' i.e.: `[data-country*="anything"]` or with data attribute of 'country' with equals any value.

I have two lists of filters (country and type) which when clicked add the filter value to an array. Then both arrays are joined to `.show()` all the items which have a data attr containing that value:

```
$("section.collaborator[data-country*='" + countryTog.join("'][data-country*='") + "'][data-collaborator_type*='" + collaborator_typeTog.join("'][data-collaborator_type*='") + "']").show('fast');
```

Is there a value which I can add to my array which will act as a wildcard as speculated above?

For example: If I hit 'Ireland' on the country filter menu and 'artist' on the type filter menu my selector looks like:

```
$(".collaborator[data-country*='ireland'][data-collaborator_type*='partner']").show();
```

or if I add another country into the mix it would look like:

```
$("section.collaborator[data-country*='ireland'][data-country*='united-kingdom'][data-collaborator_type*='partner']").show();
```

Now if I mouse up a bit and hit the 'all' button on the country filter menu I currently get:

```
$("section.collaborator[data-country*='*'][data-collaborator_type*='artist']").show();
```

What I'd like to happen then is for all the items with attribute of `data-country'[anything]'` and `data-type='artist'` to show.

I know it's possible to query for the existence of the data attribute but in this case I need to pass a value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify with an example above, Zakaria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select all elements that have a certain data attribute but you don't care what the value is, just use `[data-attribute]` without an equals sign. So if you want any country, but only artists, use `$('[data-country][data-type="artist"]')`